# How to install transliteration tool for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

How to install transliteration tool? Sometimes I need to transfer letters from Cyrillic to Latin alphabet, but there is no that option in LibreOffice.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The [LingTools add-on](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools) has a Data Conversion component that allows transliteration for any script.  Try the ICU `Any to Latin` map.  There are also other maps available, or it is possible to write a [TECkit map](https://github.com/silnrsi/teckit).

Disadvantages:

- Data Conversion is currently unstable on Linux (but works well on Windows).
- In addition to the add-on, [this large package](https://software.sil.org/fieldworks/download/) is required for Linux.

Comment: This answer seems interesting. However, the links are dead.

Comment: The links have been updated; thanks for letting me know.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. Though I am on the search for transliteration from modern Greek (and I am not on an LTS version of Ubuntu)

Comment: What didn't work - the `Any to Latin` map? There are many other mappings available, or you can create your own. If you open a new question and provide details on what is needed, then I can be of more help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132085/transliteration-from-greek-to-latin-in-spreadsheet I did install the add-on on Libreoffice 6.2.2.2, though I did not install the FieldWorks package as the available repository is for 18.04 and I am on 18.10 (and this is a production machine). The Add-on maxed out two of my cores when I selected "Data conversion"...

Comment: On Linux, it won't work without FieldWorks. So you'll either need to wait for a production release for 18.10 or try the beta repo.

Comment: Even without FieldWorks, however, it should at least show the Data Conversion dialog.  What version of LingTools did you install?  There is currently a bug in the latest version I haven't gotten around to fixing yet where it takes two tries to open some LingTools dialog windows.

Comment: LinguisticTools-3.9.1.oxt Though the add-on site mentions libreoffice 6.0 as compatible and it was last updated in August 2018. Have you tried it on 6.2?

Comment: For your needs, I would recommend the latest released version, which is LingTools 3.0.  It will probably work on LO 6.2 (although I haven't tested 6.2 yet) and should not have the dialog bug.  Hopefully sometime this year I will get a new stable release put together.

Comment: I will give it a try tommorow. Thank you for the support. And for the add-on as I understand you are involved in the development!

Comment: The Lingtools 3.0 add-on works (no crash), the filedworks repository for 18.04 however sends me through dependency hell, so I gave up on this solution for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Internation** app.

[Download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/internati/?source=directory)

It is limited to only Serbian and Uzbek alphabets, though.