# Transliteration from Greek to latin in spreadsheet

Tags: libreoffice

I am in search of an add-on to [transliterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) modern Greek text into Latin. The data is stored in .ods files, so ideally I would like to use a [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) plugin. However, I would accept a command line solution where I could parse a .csv file. Ideally, the transliteration rules would adhere to [iso 843](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_843).

What I have tried:

- https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/oootranslit Does not
  work for Greek (to be fair, it clearly states what it does)
- https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools
  Was suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797354/how-to-install-transliteration-tool-for-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1) similar (non-duplicate) question on this site. However, the installation of its dependencies on non-lts versions of Ubuntu seems too troublesome to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Lingua::Translit](https://www.netzum-sorglos.de/software/lingua-translit/) perl-module seems to provide a workaround. To install just download and extract the tar.gz file. Then run in a terminal:

```
    perl Makefile.PL
    make
    make test
    make install
```

To use:

First convert the .ods file into csv (using libreoffice) and then:

```
translit  -i input.csv -t "ISO 843" -o transliterated.csv
```

PS: I will let this question open for a few weeks, as I am confident there are solutions out there that could be used directly from Libreoffice.